# Photo contrast changes right before sharing

Tags: samsung, photos, gallery

I sometimes share pictures from the Gallery app (Samsung), but just before my sharing options come up, I can very clearly see that it increases the contrast (making it look unnatural). I have tried searching in settings, without any luck. Has anyone found a solution for this?

Samsung Galaxy
Android: 8.1.0
Samsung experience: 9.5

Comment: Older Samsung do the same. Or perhaps the targeted photo social